# Monitor receiving resolution incorrectly

Tags: ubuntu, display, resolution, xrandr

I have two displays connected to a Ge-force 210 on my Dell running Ubuntu 12.04. One is using DVI the other VGA. The DVI display had a mode for its max resolution (1680x1050) which I selected. The VGA display did not for its highest res (1280x1024). I used gtf to make a mode line, created it, added it to VGA-1 and outputted it. The display flickered and auto adjusted leaving a correct width but a stretched height.

I kept trying the auto adjust on my display. As it runs through the process the display scrolls down the stretched desktop and back to the top. When I open the monitors on-screen display it says its receiving 1280x800!, while xrandr -q says it is outputting 1280x1024 at 60hz.

This problem is likely not an xrandr problem but the screen works perfectly on a windows machine at full resolution.

Any ideas?

Comment: DVI sends the support resolutions.  VGA does not.  You need to select the correct resolution when using a VGA connection.  This sounds like a ubuntu problem have you updated and install all required drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the nvidia binary drivers or Nouveau? If the latter, file a bug on freedesktop.org or try to get help on freenode IRC in #xorg channel.

BTW the askubuntu stack exchange site might be a better fit for this very Ubuntu-specific question.

Comment: I have other problems when using the nVidia drivers as well as this one. I am trying to sort out this resolution problem on the nVidia drivers now but I prefer using Nouveau because it gives native display support in system settings.

I asked this same question in askUbuntu but didn't get an answer yet.